# Sort php array by key in arrays array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm searching for help. I found `ksort` and other sort methods for php. But i got an Array in an Array with an key called `order`. And this i want to be the order of the array

```
array(
   array("obj" => $objPage, "id" => "LogIn", "order" => 3),
   array("obj" => $objPage, "id" => "Home", "order" => 1),
   array("obj" => $objPage, "id" => "Register", "order" => 2),
   array("obj" => $objPage, "id" => "Imprint", "order" => 4), /* ... */
)
```

Now i want the array objects to sort as this:

```
array(
   array("obj" => $objPage, "id" => "Home", "order" => 1),
   array("obj" => $objPage, "id" => "Register", "order" => 2),
   array("obj" => $objPage, "id" => "LogIn", "order" => 3),
   array("obj" => $objPage, "id" => "Imprint", "order" => 4), /* ... */
)
```

Can you give me a hint how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a ['order'] == $b ['order']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a ['order'] < $b ['order']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");

print_r ($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple solution would be to use the array index itself to store the order, then use `sort` to sort the array into order and then `array_values` to re-index it?

Answer (score 0):

`array_multisort` may be valid for you:

Suposing your array is called  $myArray

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $row) {   
    $order[$key] = $row['order'];
}

array_multisort($order, SORT_ASC, $myArray)
```